# How to reload status of all widgets after login?

Tags: flutter, mobile, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Our application for job hunting, it has 2 cases:

- Already have an account.
- Access as a guest.

The problem occurs when the user accesses as a guest, then finds a favorite job and saves it, we have redirected the user to login, after the user has finished logging in. I saved the user account information in SharedPreferences and navigated the user back to the previous job details screen. What we want is that all the previous screens are logged in, because some of the previous screens we rely on the user id to show

Comment: `Navigator.push` returns a Future which will complete with the value that you pass from the Route you are pushing when you eventually invoke `Navigator.pop(context, value)`. You can use this to indicate to your previous Routes whether the user has logged in or not, and have your logic attached to that.

Comment: This is just our last resort, because there are many pages before, this will take time, whether there is a better solution.

Comment: How about an InheritedWidget above MaterialApp to hold a boolean indicating whether the user is logged in or not. Or even something as simple as a global static boolean. And then just build the pages differently based on the value of that boolean. `initState` does not get called again when you go back to a previous Route, but `build` does get called.

Comment: build is called a lot of times, I'm afraid it will affect the performance of the application, if setstate in the build

Comment: You cannot and don't need to call `setState` within `build`. You simply need to check the value of the boolean, and return the corresponding `Widget`. Isn't your requirement to build different things based on whether the user is logged in or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh your app when your loggin status change:

Add these two widget to your app:

```
class RestartWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  RestartWidget({this.child});

  static restartApp(BuildContext context) {
    final _RestartWidgetState state =
        context.ancestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher<_RestartWidgetState>());
    state.restartApp();
  }

  @override
  _RestartWidgetState createState() => new _RestartWidgetState();
}

class _RestartWidgetState extends State<RestartWidget> {
  Key key = new UniqueKey();

  void restartApp() {
    this.setState(() {
      key = new UniqueKey();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      key: key,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}

class AppBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(BuildContext) builder;

  const AppBuilder({Key key, this.builder}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  AppBuilderState createState() => new AppBuilderState();

  static AppBuilderState of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.ancestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher<AppBuilderState>());
  }
}

class AppBuilderState extends State<AppBuilder> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.builder(context);
  }

  void rebuild() {
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

Then add AppBuilder as parent of Material App:

```
AppBuilder(
  builder: (context) {
    return MaterialApp(

    );
  },
);
```

Every time you want to refresh your app's state, just call:

```
RestartWidget.restartApp(context)
```

So you can call this method when you change to loggin status and all of your page will refresh state too.

Comment: Before, there were a lot of widgets based on login status to display, we couldn't do it manually for each of these pages

Comment: I have edited other solution, you can check it out.